# WPF Glyph Run incorrectly rendering degree symbol

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, directx

I'm doing some custom controls and I have some text being drawn via Glyph Runs

My problem is that °C isn't being rendered properly by my glyphs (regardless of font family) and looks like this:

[image: Problem symbol]

So my code (simplified) for the glyph run is:

```
var typeface = new Typeface(this.FontFamily, this.FontStyle, this.FontWeight, this.FontStretch);

...

GlyphRun glyphRun = CreateGlyphRun(typeface, "°C", 10, new Point(0,0));
dc.DrawGlyphRun(brush, glyphRun);
```

Where

```
internal static GlyphRun CreateGlyphRun(Typeface typeface, string text, double size, Point origin)
{
    if (text.Length == 0)
        return null;

    GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface;

    typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface)

    var glyphIndexes = new ushort[text.Length];
    var advanceWidths = new double[text.Length];

    for (int n = 0; n < text.Length; n++)
    {
        var glyphIndex = (ushort)(text[n] - 29);
        glyphIndexes[n] = glyphIndex;
        advanceWidths[n] = glyphTypeface.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * size;
    }

    var glyphRun = new GlyphRun(glyphTypeface, 0, false, size, glyphIndexes, origin, advanceWidths, null, null,
                                null,
                                null, null, null);
    return glyphRun;
}
```

I assume its some kind of localisation issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This kind of problem is usually caused because a particular font family does not have a particular character... can you confirm that your used font *does* have that character? If not, you should be able to use a different font family just for that character.

Comment: It does as I'm using Segoe UI. If I use a textblock with Segoe UI the symbol shows up. Its only when I use the the font in a glyph run that the symbol doesn't show correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to replace

```
var glyphIndex = (ushort)(text[n] - 29);
```

with

```
var glyphIndex = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[text[n]];
```

Comment: +1 Good catch!  The original code most probably wanted to eliminate the map lookup and came up w/ the "subtract 29" formula, but that approach failed with the current font family.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [`Glyphs class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.glyphs.aspx) instead? The degree sign will show when using that:

```
<Glyphs FontUri="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\SegoeUI.TTF" FontRenderingEmSize="80" 
    StyleSimulations="BoldSimulation" UnicodeString="It's 30°C" 
    Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using a glyph run because I'm rendering via the DrawingContext (not XAML), which will only accept a GlyphRun.